# How would I optimize a tree-like graph with a significant number of redundant nodes?

Tags: graphs, optimization, trees

Recently, I was looking at the underlying data/implementation of a survey application created using a RPA tool. As a user progresses through the survey, the "decisions" reveal a predominantly tree-like structure, with some graph-related elements (there is essentially a "GO TO" component that allows a single node to share multiple parents).

As some may already figure, the described approach results in a lot of redundancy in the tree, and it gets worse the deeper you go. As a result, there are many duplicated nodes that share the exact same values, but just so happen to be the tail end of a separate unique path.

I was curious as to how, or whether it would be possible to optimize such a graph, and how one would go about doing it. I figured that a good place to start would be visually rendering it using some kind of tool, but considering there 100,000+ rows, I'm not sure how practical this would be.

Comment: Instead of a decision tree, have you thought of other representation? For example, a directed decision graph?

Comment: The issue is that the tree already exists. I’m trying to think of a way to simplify what the current state is, knowing that there is a lot of redundancy.